# gradle and eclipse plugin : sources lookup

Tags: eclipse, gradle, lookup

I'm using gradle and eclipse plugin. I've got two projects A and B (B depends on A).

in build.gradle of B, dependency on A is declared as :

```
dependencies {
 compile files(classes_output_dir_of_A)
}
```

I'm trying to have on eclipse the **sources lookup** when browsing in B project classes of A project.

I've seen on web some solutions like:

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged {
                def lib =  entries.find [...]
                lib.sourcePath = [...]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this do not work for me since B relies on classes from A (instead of jar file)

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering myself, in facts this solution works:

```
def a_project = entries.find { it.path.contains "A" }
```

Comment: But why not using Gradle project dependency instead of using the Gradle Eclipse plugin for that?